# NSURLSession Error *Crash*

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I am making a simple POST request using NSURLSession.
I am using the same method i used on the login aspect of my application.

Now i am working on a forgot pin for the user and i am getting this error:

> -[NSMutableURLRequest absoluteURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170209fd0
>   2015-04-07 11:47:26.443 ECP[358:9466] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSMutableURLRequest absoluteURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170209fd0'

I am obtaining the connection like:

```
+(void)forgotPinWebServiceCompletionHandler:(ECPForgotPinCompletionHandler)ForgotPinCompletionBlock Username:(NSString *)data {
NSError *error;

NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
[sessionConfig setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{@"Accept":@"application/json"}];
[sessionConfig setTimeoutIntervalForRequest:60.0];

/*TEST*/
NSURL * Url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://Secure//ws/auth-code/"]];

NSMutableURLRequest *forgotPinRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:Url];
[forgotPinRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
/*END TEST */

NSDictionary *credentials = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:data,@"username", nil];
NSData *userData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:credentials options:0 error:&error];
[forgotPinRequest setHTTPBody:userData];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig];
[session dataTaskWithURL:forgotPinRequest completionHandler:ForgotPinCompletionBlock];
```

}

I am getting the error on the last line in the method

```
[session dataTaskWithURL:forgotPinRequest completionHandler:ForgotPinCompletionBlock];
```

I cant seem to figure out exactly what is causing this issue and how i should go about fixing it. What could help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "forgotPinRequest" is of "NSMutableURLRequest" whereas the dataTaskWithURL expects it to be simple NSURL type. This is where it is failing. Make sure to use the appropriate method of NSMutableURLRequest to get the URL object.

Comment: Sorry for not noticing this difference, what would be the proper method? I need the mutable url request because i am passing the JSON in the body and need to be able to POST it.

Comment: - (NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request completionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error))completionHandler NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE(NSURLSESSION_AVAILABLE, 7_0);

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! i didnt realize it was off by one word haha